# If statement on Sheet Range

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am writing and Excel VBA if statement, but I can't figure out why it is not working.

I have 1 Sheet called "Data" and I want to check if some variables in column I are the same as in my ActiveSheet row 2, column B (which is number 2). I used the following code which ends automatically because it is not working. Anybody an idea?

Example:

```
Sub test()

If Sheets("Data").Range("I:I") = ActiveSheet(2, 2) Then
MsgBox ("Yes")
Else
MsgBox ("No")
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a loop in column `I` if you want to validate every item in that column; use a flag to bail out as soon as you find a mismatching value, so as to avoid looping through all cells once you already know the outcome:

```
Dim x as long, result As Boolean
result = True

For x = 1 to 100 'let's say up to row 100
   If Worksheets("Data").Range("I" & x).value <> ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).value Then
       result = False
   End If
   If Not result Then Exit For
Next x

If result Then 
    MsgBox "Yes" 
Else 
    MsgBox "No"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, in the end I don't need the MsgBoxes it was just to see what happens in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You compare a whole column (i.e. 1048576 values) with a single value which obviously does not work. Furthermore if you want to access a specific cell you have to use the Cells-collection of your worksheet i.e. `ActiveSheet.Cells(2,2)`

If you want to compare each cell in column I individually, use a Loop. If you only want to know if the search-value exists somewhere within the column, you can use the Range.Find method.